# To inetd or not to inetd... when should I use inetd for my network server program?

Tags: network-programming, inetd

Can anyone give a concise set of real-world considerations that would drive the choice of whether or not to use inetd to manage a program that acts as a network server?

(If inetd is used, I think it alters the requirements around networking code in the program, so I think it's definitely programming-related and not general IT)

The question is based around an implementation I've seen that uses a control program managed by inetd to start a network listener that then runs forever and takes constant and heavy load. It didn't seem like a good fit with the textbook inetd usage profile (on-demand, infrequently used, lightweight) and got me interested in the more general question.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

It depends on the usage pattern for your service. If the startup time for your daemon is low, and you expect it to be used infrequently, then inted might be a good fit. It reduces or even eliminates the need to write any additional networking code.

If your daemon is more heavyweight or more frequently used, you're probably better off writing it standalone. You can just as easily write an `init.d` script and some `conf.d` configuration to go with it and it will be no harder for an admin to manage. Most programming languages these days have easy to use socket libraries so in many cases the networking code may not even be that difficult.

I've found in my experience that few admins these days are familiar with inetd. Most daemons just provide their own init script. In fact, of the few hundred systems which I manage I can't think of a single one that launches anything through inetd at all. That's something worth considering.

Answer (score 2):

Hooking into inetd will make your service slightly easier to manage from an operational point of view as inetd allows a sysadmin to control practically all of how network communications with your program happens. However it will require you to make a few code changes to your program. Also, it may not be as efficient as just making your program run as a daemon to begin with.

EDIT: I personally never use inetd and always opt to write server processes as standalone daemons.

Answer (score 2):

I think another factor worth considering when deciding to use inetd is how much memory the process handling the request consumes on an average? If this is fairly high, then under high load you risk running out of memory (since inetd forks). The same server might be implementable in a multithreaded or select-poll manner possibly allowing for higher load / less memory per connection.

Answer (score 1):

You can use inetd to give TCP/UDP capabilities to simple programs that operate over stdin/stdout.

Without inetd, your program will need to manage a slew of concerns, including network interfaces, sockets, forking, resource limits, etc.

Comment: Wow that's good to know. Are you aware of any real-world example one could look at please?

Comment: For example, you could write a simple [postfix content filter](https://www.postfix.org/FILTER_README.html#advanced_filter) in perl without dealing with connection handling. Postfix implements its own inetd-like interface via [master.cf](https://www.postfix.org/master.5.html). Other (perhaps better) inetd-like software exists, too, such as [ucspi-tcp](http://cr.yp.to/ucspi-tcp.html)

Answer (score 0):

What alternative strategy are you considering?

inetd is a good way of ensuring your server starts when the OS boots in the appropriate run level.  Even if you do design your server to have some other management mechanism, inetd could still wrap all the commands quite simply.  It's only shell scripts after all.

Comment: Well - the alternative strategy would be to run the network program directly I guess, started from an rc.d script

Comment: Actually, so maybe Windows/UNIX compatibility is a reason why you would choose inetd

Comment: seeing mcrute's response just shows me how little I know about inetd.  However many apps I've used/developed runs a daemon, then scripts are added to inetd to start/stop them.  I guess the equivalent in windows is to install as a service.